# Top nav bar of my blogger website is not visible in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, blogger

I am creating a blog on blogspot using a third party theme. I am facing an issue that the top navigation bar containing about us, contact us and social buttons is working properly in desktop theme but it is not showing up in mobile view. Here is the blog link: https://www.zainabfit.blogspot.com
Suggest me a solution for that issue. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

I have tried all the possible solutions that i find on the internet but nothing works for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the css then you can remove `#top-bar` from this selector

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px)
#top-bar, .header-logo, .header-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

so it would look like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px)
.header-logo, .header-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

It is coming from the style tag with id `page-skin-1` which is in your head tag.